# Building two versions of maven artefacts

Tags: maven, dependencies

A dependency that [we](https://github.com/WestRidgeSystems/jmisb) rely on (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/ffmpeg) has recently split into a LGPL and GPL version, depending on how the underlying ffmpeg is configured.
There are two different sets of artifacts that are released (e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/ffmpeg-platform-gpl/4.3.2-1.5.5 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/ffmpeg-platform/4.3.2-1.5.5).

The API is the same for our purposes - we don't need to change our code. Its dynamic at runtime in terms of what is supported, but that is OK. Its already flexible given different hardware support.

I'd like to build two sets of artifacts as a parallel path up through our tree (e.g. two versions of core, api, viewer, examples, etc) as jar with different license dependencies to allow the user to choose which one they prefer. The goal is that the user can  choose a particular version of our code and the dependencies "just work" in that the right dependencies are either included in the uber-jar or get pulled in via maven.

So I have a `jmisb-api-lgpl-${version}.pom/jar` (and maybe jar-with-dependency uber-jar) that depends on `jmisb-core-lgpl-${version}.[pom, jar]` that in turn depends on `ffmpeg-platform-${other version}.[pon,jar]`. And built at the same time, `jmisb-api-gpl-${version}.pom/jar` that depends on `jmisb-core-gpl-${version}.[pom,jar]` that in turn depends on `ffmpeg-platform-gpl-${other version}.jar`.

What is the preferred / recommended way to do that, or alternatively, what is a relatively clean way that builds both without needing to manually select which one to generate?

Comment: First mvnrepository is not central repository. This is central: https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.bytedeco%20ffmpeg The question is: If the api etc. are identical then you need to create only a single set of artifacts which define needed parts as provided which the user has to define as dependency (either the one with lgpg or with gpl..) .. ?

Comment: It's possible to have both sets of artifacts, for example, in the same final uber JAR, but it doesn't make sense to do that because in that case the GPL applies at build time anyway. Could you clarify what the goal is? You could, for example, provide the GPL JARs separately, have users add them to some random directory somewhere when they want them, and get that loaded by your application when it finds them.

Comment: @SamuelAudet  added some more text on the goal. I am trying to make it as simple as I can for consumers.

Comment: If you're using Maven, we can use profiles to change dependencies at build time...

Comment: I was hoping to avoid profile based selection, and just build it in one go. Profiles are definitely a valid fallback if I can't sort it any other way though.

Comment: @khmarbaise Valid criticism on the repo. I was trying to show both were published, rather than where, but the expression is poor, and I've reworded it. I don't really need different jar content (because the classes are same), just different pom to reflect the right dependencies, and corresponding different uber-jar. I want the selection of the top level maven dependency to pull in only the required (by license) implicit dependencies.

Comment: It sounds like you already have multiple pom.xml files for both "paths", which I think already does everything you need. What's missing exactly?

Comment: I have a single pom.xml for each module, and would like to keep it like that. I just want two outputs (same except for LGPL dependency vs GPL dependency) where I currently have one.